# Html text overflow causes element shift

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make 3 area same size with ability to hide overflowed text and make it ellipses. For that, i wrote next code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.end {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.first, .second {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.third {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="first">
      <span style="">sadasd2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</span>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <span>123</span>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <span>123</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="end">
  </div>
</div>
```

Despite the text in the first element overflowed and hidden, it causes second element to it to be shifted. Why does it happens this way?

Comment: try using max-width property.

Comment: I would like to make areas as width as possible in proportion

Comment: I assume it is an Internet Explorer issue. Your code works fine in chrome.

Comment: to the far right there is should be a black square. <div class="end">
  </div>

Comment: `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is not working for all browsers. This is a known issue in Internet Explorer 10 and Internet Explorer 11, but it works for Internet Explorer 5 and Internet Explorer 7

Comment: i use chrome browser

Comment: Could you please upload what you see, as a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `width: 0` to `.first, .second`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.end {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}

.first, .second {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  width: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.third {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px red solid;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="first">
      <span style="">sadasd2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222</span>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <span>123</span>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <span>123</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="end">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why i should add width if i already set flex 1 1 0;